# Distinguishing between types of recorder calibration

Tags: methods, calibration, terminology

I have come across many terms to describe different types of recorder calibrations (e.g., end-to-end calibration, point calibration, factory calibration) and the whole topic of recorder calibration was very confusing for me when I started in bioacoustics. I had a hard time finding beginner-level (i.e., not highly technical, jargon-filled) material describing calibration, and even now, I still at times question whether I'm using the correct terminology.

I was wondering if anyone would be able to provide a concise summary of the different types or methods of recorder calibration and perhaps when they might be more or less recommended.

I also wonder if the calibration categories and recommendations tend to be similar for air and underwater recordings. (For me, I have only worked with underwater recorders, so I'm not very familiar with air recording methods.)

Thank you for any help you can offer!

Comment: You must have read my mind -- I was just googling this very thing!

Answer (score 6):

I looked up the Bible of Underwater Acoustics (Urick 1983) and found the following overview
[image]

There are 12 methods mentioned with 27 references!

Anyhow, the simplest method is to compare the sensor in question with a calibrated one. In underwater you compare the recording with the direct measurements of a calibrated hydrophone.

Answer (score 2):

From a terrestrial sound perspective, I've seen analogous calibration methods to those pointed out by @WMXZ. See chapter contents from [i] below.

[image]

On a regular basis though, I've only so far seen the substitution method (measuring the playback sound with a quality calibration mic, and then switching it with the target mic and comparing the recorded signals.

References

i) Wong, G.S. (2014). Microphones and Their Calibration. In: Rossing, T.D. (eds) Springer Handbook of Acoustics. Springer Handbooks. Springer, New York, NY.

Answer (score 1):

You can either:

1. Trust the cal sheet of the microphone
2. use a pistonphone to check sensitivity at one frequency (typically 250 or 1000 Hz)
3. do a relative calibration where you measure a sound field with a known microphone and then insert your unknown microphone in the same sound field to work out its sensitivity.